# What does the sentence 'He makes a good case' mean？

Tags: british-english

> ...Garfield isn’t fogeyish; the final quarter of his book is devoted to Wikipedia, which he sees as a worthy heir to its printed forbears, and in some ways a realization of their aspirations. But what he does suggest is that those predecessors deserve a little more love and attention.
>
> ***He makes a good case***, taking delight in the nuggets of treasure he unearths and sharing them generously—the final chapter of this alphabetically arranged book consists of a small anthology of “Z” entries he happens to find diverting...

Answer (score 1):

The cited usage is full Oxford English Dictionary definition 7b - which was originally "domain-specific" to *legal* cases (court cases, legal actions)...

> **case**
> *The sum of arguments presented by one side in a legal action; the facts forming the basis for such arguments. **In extended use:** a set of facts or arguments supporting one side in a debate or controversy; a valid set of arguments. Frequently with **for, against** (a party to the dispute, an argument).*

I don't know exactly *what* case / argument Garfield makes so well, but obviously anyone reading the full text will know what point he's making.

Comment: It appears from the context given that the case Garfield makes so well is that the predecessors to Wikipedia deserve more love and attention than what they generally get.

Comment: I think to all intents and purposes, chatgtp has already made even wikipedia redundant, let alone all their unsung hero predecessors.